# Buttons with graphics

Tags: java

I am creating a simple game to teach myself how to use JAVA properly. Now I'm creating game states, For example: main menu state, game state, settings state. I've run into this problem that I have to have buttons in my main menu state.

> MMenuState.java:

```
public class MMenuState extends State {

    private Button PGameBtn;

    public MMenuState() {

    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        PGameBtn = new Button("Play game");
        PGameBtn.setBackground(Color.RED);
        PGameBtn.setFont(new Font("Plain", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        add(PGameBtn);
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        Font MFont = new Font("TimeNewRoman", 1, 20);
        g.setFont(MFont);
        g.drawString("This is the main menu", 10, 100);
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't add the button to the state. How could I implement a button in this state?